# Log4j2: Logs not sent to Console where as logs to file works fine

Tags: log4j2

I am a newbie to log4j. My log4j configuration is not writing logs to Console where as the logs to File is working fine. I am not able to troubleshoot this issue inspite of refering earlier posts.
I have two appenders - one for Console and the other for File. I intend to write ERROR and FATAL to file hence using level=ERROR. I intend to write all logs to console hence using level=TRACE for Console.
My code contains just one package named 'parallel', has one class named ClassA with one method that logs all types of logs.

If I specify both Console and File appenders within Root tag then my expectations are met. If I move the File appender outside Root and mention it under Logger tag then only File appender works where as Console appender does not work. Is it mandatory that all appenders be placed under Root tag?

```
package parallel;
public class ClassA {
private final   Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(ClassA.class);
@Test 
public void testLogs() {
    log.info("info");
    log.debug("debug");
    log.warn("warn");
    log.error("error");
    log.fatal("fatal");
    log.trace("trace");
}
```

}

```
<Configuration status="INFO">
<Properties>
   <Property name="basePath" value="./logs" />
</Properties>
<Appenders>
  <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
    <PatternLayout>
     <Pattern>
     [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
     </Pattern>
    </PatternLayout>
  </Console>
  <File name="fileLogger" fileName="${basePath}/error.log">
    <PatternLayout>
    <Pattern>
     [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
    </Pattern>
    </PatternLayout>
  </File>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
   <Root name="parallel">
     <AppenderRef ref="console" level="trace" />
   </Root>
   <Logger name="parallel" level="warn" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="fileLogger" />
   </Logger>
</Loggers>
```

Comment: Just to check if Root tag is working fine I mentioned invalid appender ref value in Root tag. The program errors saying unable to locate the appender which means my original ref to Console appender is fine. Not sure what could be wrong with Console tag

Comment: most likely your System.out and/or err streams are being redirected.

Comment: Not sure what is meant by redirecting system.out. Console output is working fine when both Appenders are placed under root

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it, your goal is to accomplish these items:

> I intend to write ERROR and FATAL to file hence using level=ERROR.  I
>   intend to write all logs to console hence using level=TRACE for
>   Console.

**Please read the entire answer before making a final choice regarding what you will implement in your code.**

You ***could*** do this by configuring your loggers as follows:

```
<Loggers>
    <Root>
        <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
    </Root>
    <Logger name="parallel" level="ALL" additivity="true">
        <AppenderRef ref="fileLogger" level="ERROR"/>
    </Logger>
</Loggers>
```

Log events will be accepted by each **logger** based on logger name and the level of the event. If you call `log.error(...)` for example an `ERROR` level event is generated. If `log` was obtained through `LogManager.getLogger(ClassA.class)` then log4j will search its configuration for a logger called "parallel.ClassA". If it does not find such a logger it will go [up the hierarchy](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/architecture.html) to a less specific logger - "parallel". If this logger does not exist it will go to the root logger.

Once the logger is identified log4j must determine if the event is *accecpted* by that logger. This is based on the level setting for the logger. Since the "parallel" logger is set to a level of `ALL` it will accept events of any level.

After the logger accepts an event, its appenders must also accept the event. The level associated with file appender of the "parallel" logger is `ERROR` so this appender will only accept events that are `ERROR` and `FATAL` level.

Since additivity is `true` for "parallel" logger whenever it accepts an event it will pass that event to the [appenders of all of its parent loggers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51905527/3284624) as well (unless one of them breaks the chain by specifying additivity `false` - see [log4j2 architecture page](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/architecture.html) for details). So any events accepted by "parallel" will go to the console appender associated with root logger.

**There is a problem with this approach** in that if a log event reached the root logger with a level of ERROR or FATAL it would not be written to your log file. The logs would "leak" to the console. This can happen if you accidentally write some bad code or if you accidentally forget to update your configuration file after adding some new code.

Here's some sample code to illustrate the problem:

```
package parallel;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class ClassA {
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(ClassA.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.info("info");
        log.debug("debug");
        log.warn("warn");
        log.error("error");
        log.fatal("fatal");
        log.trace("trace");

        // See the mistake here? 
        // The wrong logger name was used in the code, 
        // now the error event goes to the root logger!
        final Logger log2 = LogManager.getLogger("foo");
        log2.error("Woops an error!");
    }
}
```

The **console output** for the above using the configuration from the beginning of the answer is:

```
[INFO ] 2019-05-05 12:48:31.410 [main] ClassA - info
[DEBUG] 2019-05-05 12:48:31.411 [main] ClassA - debug
[WARN ] 2019-05-05 12:48:31.411 [main] ClassA - warn
[ERROR] 2019-05-05 12:48:31.411 [main] ClassA - error
[FATAL] 2019-05-05 12:48:31.412 [main] ClassA - fatal
[TRACE] 2019-05-05 12:48:31.412 [main] ClassA - trace
[ERROR] 2019-05-05 12:48:31.413 [main] foo - Woops an error!
```

The **error log file** only shows:

```
[ERROR] 2019-05-05 12:48:31 [main] ClassA - error
[FATAL] 2019-05-05 12:48:31 [main] ClassA - fatal
```

The simplest fix is to just move all of your appenders to the root logger as shown below:

```
<Loggers>
    <Root level="ALL">
        <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="fileLogger" level="ERROR"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

Now all events are accepted by root logger and console appender but only ERROR and FATAL events are accepted by the file appender. Now even with incorrect code the log events will go to the right place.

**Console ouput:**

```
[INFO ] 2019-05-05 12:59:32.419 [main] ClassA - info
[DEBUG] 2019-05-05 12:59:32.421 [main] ClassA - debug
[WARN ] 2019-05-05 12:59:32.421 [main] ClassA - warn
[ERROR] 2019-05-05 12:59:32.421 [main] ClassA - error
[FATAL] 2019-05-05 12:59:32.421 [main] ClassA - fatal
[TRACE] 2019-05-05 12:59:32.421 [main] ClassA - trace
[ERROR] 2019-05-05 12:59:32.422 [main] foo - Woops an error!
```

**Error log file:**

```
[ERROR] 2019-05-05 12:59:32 [main] ClassA - error
[FATAL] 2019-05-05 12:59:32 [main] ClassA - fatal
[ERROR] 2019-05-05 12:59:32 [main] foo - Woops an error!
```

Other Possibly Helpful Links:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51567436/3284624

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Great explanation. Now I get the logic. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Partially solved.....
I added Additivity="true" in the Logger tag and this made the logs print in both Console and File. However the log level of ERROR was being applied to both Console and File. My actual requirement is Console to have TRACE and File to have ERROR level.
I am not able to understand the concept of Additivity from log4j2 official doc. Anyone who could explain this concept would be of great help.